# from . import views ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, django, import, view

i just start to use django, and i got error when try to import in the "from . import views" part, this is my code

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home')
]
```

and i have error message, which is
"ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"
can you show why it error, and the solution

Answer (score 1):

try

```
from <app_name> import views
```

due to low reputation I am writing answer or else I could post it in comments

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. It was happening because I was trying to run the script 'urls.py' by itself.
You need to run the django project as a whole by running the runserver command,
python manage.py runserver in the terminal